# Improve stability on connection to AWS IOT Core connection

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, disconnect

I'm trying to use AWS IoT with Python. I'm implementing an MQTT client:

```
#Exte codigo SOLO SIRVE para escritorio
#NO USARLO en una PYCOM

#
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient 
from pathlib import Path
import time

#
cert_folder=Path("certificados")

# user specified callback function
def customCallback(client, userdata, message):
    print("Received a new message: ")
    print(message.payload)
    print("from topic: ")
    print(message.topic)
    print("--------------\n\n")

# AWS general configuration
AWS_PORT = 8883
AWS_HOST = '*****.amazonaws.com'
AWS_ROOT_CA = cert_folder / "*****.pem"
AWS_CLIENT_CERT = cert_folder / "*****.cert.pem"
AWS_PRIVATE_KEY = cert_folder / "*****.private.key"

# For certificate based connection
myMQTTClient = AWSIoTMQTTClient("Pycom-client")
# For Websocket connection
# myMQTTClient = AWSIoTMQTTClient("Pycom-client", useWebsocket=True)

# Configurations
# For TLS mutual authentication
myMQTTClient.configureEndpoint(AWS_HOST, 8883)
# For Websocket
# myShadowClient.configureEndpoint(AWS_HOST, 443)
myMQTTClient.configureCredentials(AWS_ROOT_CA, AWS_PRIVATE_KEY, AWS_CLIENT_CERT)
# For Websocket, we only need to configure the root CA
# myMQTTClient.configureCredentials(AWS_ROOT_CA)

myMQTTClient.configureOfflinePublishQueueing(-1)  # Infinite offline Publish queueing
myMQTTClient.configureDrainingFrequency(2)  # Draining: 2 Hz
myMQTTClient.configureConnectDisconnectTimeout(10)  # 10 sec
myMQTTClient.configureMQTTOperationTimeout(50)  # 5 sec

#
if myMQTTClient.connect():
    print('AWS connection succeeded')

myMQTTClient.publish("topic_1", "Hola AWS!!!", 0)

# Subscribe to topic
myMQTTClient.subscribe("topic_2", 1, customCallback)

myMQTTClient.disconnect()

#Ciclo principal
while True:

    myMQTTClient.connect()

    myMQTTClient.publish("topic_1", "Hola AWS!!!", 0)

    # Subscribe to topic
    myMQTTClient.subscribe("topic_2", 1, customCallback)

    myMQTTClient.disconnect()
```

However, the connection still is very unstable. I receive timeout or server rejection messages very often. I can send a couple of messages and receive some others. But it is difficult to receive messages via subscription and I don't know if I should use additional code in order to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you would like to publish MQTT messages to AWS IoT Core from your device using Python. Also, you want to see messages published by subscribing the relevant topic. The main problem in your code is that you do not establish a persistent session with the AWS IoT message broker. In your `while` statement, you connect, publish, subscribe, and disconnect constantly.

I would recommend that you update your code similar to the following:

```
# Connect and subscribe to AWS IoT
myMQTTClient.connect()
myMQTTClient.subscribe(your_topic_name, 1, customCallback)
time.sleep(1)
 
# Publish to the same topic in a loop forever
while True:
    myMQTTClient.publish(your_topic_name, "Hola AWS!!!", 0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

You do not need `myMQTTClient.disconnect()` in this example because you have an infinite while loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer so it is not neccesary to desconect?

Comment: Not necessary in your case. Yet this is definitively not always the case. Hope it helps.